# JavaScript Sharing Dialog doesn't work on folders and some files

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the sharing dialog (https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing) but it doesn't seem to work on folders or files not opened in the app.  I can understand the latter, but is there any way to use the sharing dialog on the folders?